# Apache Velocity not rendering CSS transform tag

Tags: java, css, templates, velocity, apache-velocity

I am trying to rotate the obtained image using CSS. I have checked the same using plain vanilla HTML CSS and the image is indeed being rotated.

Below is my code for the same :

CSS :

```
.transform-right{
  transform : rotate(90deg);
}
```

HTML :

```
<center> 
 <img class="transform-right" src="/home/ags/Documents/barcode/T20180398.png" alt="!Barcode" width="300px" height="100px" style="padding : 500px 300px 0px 180px;"> </center>
```

Its tested and working as expected.

But the same is not working in **Apache Velocity Template**. Tags are all same and there is no change at all. The image is getting fetched but **not** being rotated.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: It's not clear what not working and why do you show only specific CSS/HTML?

Comment: The image is not being rotated in velocity

Comment: is your CSS in external file? if so how do you include it?

Comment: No. Its an inline css inside <style> tags

Comment: Are you sure there's no additional `transform-right` class is loaded ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bVuhLju9

Here is my file

Comment: The transform tag and barcode image are just one above another.

Comment: Please add to the question the *generated* HTML/CSS relevant section.